# How do I log to both console and log file with OpenSSH sshd?

Tags: ssh

Due to some circumstances we need to log OpenSSH sshd output to console, but we would also want to be able to log it to file. This would be something like running `sshd -e -E /path/to/file.log ...`. However, it seems as if -E is overriding, so if used, it will not log to console.

Is it possible to configure sshd to do both at the same time?

BR

Patrik

Answer (score 1):

Log to syslog. Your log server can be configured to send output to both console and a file.

Comment: In our case this is not really possible, as we do not have sudo on the host. We start an sshd session to be able to do file transfer to a local temporary SFTP server.